# Order actual SQL data on a single new column

Tags: sql-server

I got a few columns of data:

```
A1, A2, A3... AN
```

And every column can have common data with the others:

```
A1, A2, A3... AN
-------------------
P1, P4, P2, P3
P2, P3, P1, P3
```

And I want to get all that data in a single column ordered with a separator like:

```
A1, A2, A3... AN, ORDERED_DATA
---------------------------------
P1, P4, P2, P3, P1 | P2 | P3 | P4
P2, P3, P1, P3, P1 | P2 | P3 | P3
```

I need a SELECT query doing that. I don't know how ordering that before concat. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a primary key on your data.. i.e. ID

Comment: yes, imagine and ID before the data cols. The ID is not included in the ORDERED_DATA

Comment: Having multiple columns containing the same "type" of data is usually a sign of a broken data model. It usually means that you've modelled things as columns where you should have modelled them as additional *rows* (in the current or a separate table). That way, if the `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` values currently embedded in column names is *significant*, it can be modelled as a separate column and as *data* rather than metadata.

Comment: I didn't modeled that database, it is from a 3rd party provider and I work on "black closed box"

Comment: How big is the table?

Comment: not much, but don't worry bout the size

Comment: You may have to do this with a Cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can probably do something like this using FOR XML to concatenate the values

```
SELECT  A1, A2, A3, A4, 
        STUFF(ca.data, 1, 3, '') AS Ordered_Data 
FROM    myTable
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT ' | ' + t.v
                     FROM ( VALUES(A1), (A2), (A3), (A4) ) t(v)
                     ORDER BY t.v
                     FOR XML PATH('')
                    ) ca(data)
```

if you have null values, you probably want to use `WHERE t.v IS NOT NULL` in the outer apply query

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Table table (id int,A1 varchar(10),A2 varchar(10),A3 varchar(10),A4 varchar(10))
Insert Into @Table values 
(1,'P1','P4','P2','P3'),
(2,'P2','P3','P1','P3')

;with cteNorm as (
    Select id,Val = A1 From @Table
    Union All
    Select id,Val = A2 From @Table
    Union All
    Select id,Val = A3 From @Table
    Union All
    Select id,Val = A4 From @Table
)
Select id, Ordered = STUFF((
    SELECT ' | ' + val FROM cteNorm
    WHERE id = x.id
    Order by id,Val
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
FROM cteNorm AS x
GROUP BY id
```

Returns

```
id  Ordered
1   P1 | P2 | P3 | P4
2   P1 | P2 | P3 | P3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method in addition to the other answers, using `UNPIVOT` and `STUFF`/`FOR XML`:

```
SELECT  t.ID,
        t.A1,
        t.A2,
        t.A3,
        t.A4,
        STUFF((
               SELECT   ' | ' + unpvt.Val
               FROM     @table
               UNPIVOT ( Val FOR Col IN (A1, A2, A3, A4) ) unpvt
               WHERE    unpvt.ID = t.ID
               ORDER BY unpvt.Val
               FOR XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 3, '') AS ORDERED_DATA
FROM    @table AS t;
```

[Working example](https://gist.github.com/chrispickford/2e9b466975cf4bd49befe45c22e21227)

```
ID  A1  A2  A3  A4  ORDERED_DATA
1   P1  P4  P2  P3  P1 | P2 | P3 | P4
2   P2  P3  P1  P3  P1 | P2 | P3 | P3
```